# Store a Char from command line to Char array in C

Tags: c

I'm having trouble when I try to store the stdin in a program inside char array variable.

It throws a segfault when it goes by these lines:

`procNames[processNumber] = argv[1];`

and

`strcpy(procNames[processNumber], proc[0]);`

How can I store the chars in the array procNames?

The usage is:

`(stdin) <CHAR>: <NUMBER>`

I want to store every `<CHAR>` and every `<NUMBER>` introduced by order. The `<NUMBER>` stores without erros, the `<CHAR>` storage throws the segmentation fault.

```
char line[80],proc[80];

// Storing
char procNames[80];
int procPorts[80];

// To iterate
int processNumber = 0;
int actualProcessNumber = 0;

[...]

for(;fgets(line,80,stdin);) {

    sscanf(line,"%[^:]: %d",proc,&port);

    [...]

    if(strcmp(proc,argv[1]) == 0) {
        if (repeatedProc == false) {
            procNames[processNumber] = argv[1];
            procPorts[processNumber] = puerto_udp;
            actualProcessNumber = processNumber;
            processNumber++;
        }

    } else {
        if (repeatedProc == false) {
            strcpy(procNames[processNumber], proc[0]);
            procPorts[processNumber] = port;
            processNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Understand that the *Command Line* for a program is not `stdin`. It is an argument list that is passed by the shell to your program on startup. `stdin` is a separate and distinct standard string that allows you to read input from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the issues you get:

#### 1.

You need

```
char procNames[N][80];
```

instead of

```
char procNames[80];
```

where `N` gives the amount of strings to hold in `procNames`. `[80] - 1` just specifies the maximum amount of characters possible in each string.

#### 2.

You cannot *assign* arrays with strings by the `=` operator in C. Use `strcpy()` instead.

Replace

```
procNames[processNumber] = argv[1];
```

with

```
strcpy( procNames[processNumber], argv[1] );
```

#### 3.

```
strcpy(procNames[processNumber], proc[0]);
```

1. The second argument of needs to be a pointer to `char`, `proc[0]` is of type `char`. Use `proc` only.
2. `proc` has no string in it to copy. Use at least `char proc[80] = "";` to not get a runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

Your `procNames` is an array of characters, not an array of pointers. Arrays cannot be assigned, just copied, and `procNames[processNumber] = argv[1]` should actually issue a warning / an error.

Further, as you intend to have an array of - let's say - 10 such names, you probably mean

```
char procNames[10][80];
```

Then you can write

```
strcpy(procNames[processNumber],argv[1]);
```

to copy the contents of the string `argv[1]` points to.
Furhter, in order to avoid that you exceed the length of a `procNames`-entry, I suggest to use

```
strncpy(procNames[processNumber],argv[1],80);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to fix the first part, thx a million!

Answer (score 2):

You defined `char procNames[80];` which means it's a string that can hold 80 characters (also counting the 0-terminator at the end).

Later one you're doing this `procNames[processNumber] = argv[1];` where `procNames[processNumber]` points to a character and `argv[1]` is a string holding the first command line parameter. So in fact you're trying to assign a pointer to a char.

Your compiler must have at least warned you about this.

Make sure to really look at compiler output as it often tries to tell you what you are doing wrong.